# Access - SQL Query to allocate inventory stocks to orders

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to SQL & MS Access. I have a problem with Access SQL Query. I have a table with the current inventory status and another table with upcoming deliveries. I want to allocate the current order stock to upcoming deliveries.

**Stock table**

```
S_Material | S_Order | S_Order_Item | S_Size | Stock

YRN1       | S1      | I1           | S      | 500
YRN1       | S2      | I2           | S      | 600    
YRN2       | S1      | I1           | M      | 500    
YRN2       | S2      | I2           | L      | 600
```

**Delivery table**

```
P_Material | P_Order | P_Order_Item | P_Size | P_required_Qty

YRN1       | S10     | I10          | S      | 800    
YRN2       | S20     | I20          | M      | 300    
YRN2       | S30     | I30          | L      | 300    
YRN2       | S40     | I40          | L      | 300
```

**Expected output**

"Qty to take" field is the one to update by the assignment.

```
P_Mat | P_Ord| P_O_It| P_Sz| P_req_Qty| S_Mat| S_Ord| S_O_I | S_Sz | Qty_to_Take

 YRN1 | S10  | I10   | S   | 800      | YRN1 | S1   | I1    | S    | 500
 YRN1 | S10  | I10   | S   | 800      | YRN1 | S2   | I2    | S    | 300
 YRN2 | S20  | I20   | M   | 300      | YRN2 | S1   | I1    | M    | 300
 YRN2 | S30  | I30   | L   | 300      | YRN2 | S2   | I2    | L    | 300
 YRN2 | S40  | I40   | L   | 300      | YRN2 | S2   | I2    | L    | 300
```

Note: When allocating the stocks, Sometimes it would need to take from multiple lines in the Stock table, and sometimes, one stock could be distributed into multiple orders. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please translate this *I want to allocate the current order stock to upcoming deliveries* to actual math. Relatedly, illustrate your problem with data (current and desired results) and not just field names and show us what SQL you attempted.

Comment: You don't show Qty_to_Take as a field in table. This would be a calculated value? Not clear what you are trying to accomplish. Why do you need to 'allocate', why not just calculate balances? Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: @Parfait I have added some example data.

Comment: @June7 Actually we extracting this data from an ERP system weekly and transfer the leftover stock from completed orders to planned orders. What I need to do is do this allocation from here and export to an Excel file and upload the same to the ERP system and the transfer part happens there. I did not mention that part here to avoid the question been compliacted.

Comment: I doubt this can be accomplished with query alone and will involve complex VBA.

Comment: @June7, To be honest, I did this in Excel with VBA. I'm not an expert but somehow managed to accomplish. The problem with excel is it takes hours to finish the task. could be since I'm a newbie and did it in using hard ways.

Comment: So my comments still apply. I don't understand need to 'allocate' (associate) specific stock records to specific delivery records. Stock received and stock taken are transactions that can be used to calculate stock balance. What you want is complicated programming and beyond scope of SO.